# What is the integral $\int dF(x)$ when $F$ is a differentiable cumulative distribution function?

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory

My probability professor says $\int dF(x)=1-F(x)$, and I don't understand why. I know $\int dF(x)=\int f(x)dx$ since $F$ is differentiable and $f$ is the pdf of $F$, but could someone help me out why this is the case?

Also, if this is true, what would be $\int dF(x,y)$? when $F$ is a bivarate cdf?

Comment: $\int dF(x)=1$, so not $1-F(x)$. Further $1-F(x)$ can be recognized as $\int\mathbb1_{(x,\infty)}(y)dF(y)=P(X>x)$ where $F$ denotes the CDF of $X$.

Comment: for your last question: if $f\in C^1(\Bbb R^n,\Bbb R)$ then $$df=\partial_1 fdx^1+\partial_2 fdx^2+\ldots+\partial_n fdx^n$$ In your case $$dF(x,y)=\partial_x F(x,y)\,dx+\partial_y F(x,y)\,dy$$